# Min - second lowest number using non adjacent ranges

Tags: excel, min

I understand the min formula as a standard and have created the below formula to find the min value across to non adjacent ranges

[=MIN(G14:I12, K14:M14)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGtye.png)

But what I need is to find the second smallest number but am experiences many errors

[=MIN((G14:I12, K14:M14),2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8bWl.png)

this returns the value of 2, and if i add indirect I receive an error, any thoughts on the correct way of finding the second lowest number from non adjacent ranges?

=MIN(INDIRECT(("G14:I12", "K14:M14"),2))

Comment: What would be your expected result `45`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want second minimum number then could try `SMALL()` function. Try-

```
=SMALL(G2:M2,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, so it still through up an error as I didn't want column J included in this calculation, but it was just about applying the brackets in the right place
=SMALL((F10:H10,J10:L10),2)

Comment: What would be your result then?

Comment: Give a try on `=MIN(SMALL(F10:H10,2),SMALL(J10:L10,2))`

Comment: @Harun24hr Why two `SMALL` functions? `SMALL` accepts array unions, as per the OP's comment, i.e. `=SMALL((G12:I14,K14:M14),2)`

Comment: @JosWoolley That's correct. I am confused actually what op wants.